# Inconsistent margins between two background images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make two separate "layers" of background by putting the contents of my webpage inside a div. The layer of background I put for the div is clipped before it reaches the edge of the screen, but the one set as a regular body background image isn't. I can't find anything in my HTML or CSS that would affect the margin of the div. Setting min-height & min-width of body to 100% creates overflow.

HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
(content)
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg{
  background-image: url('bg1.png');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  margin: 0px 0px
}
body{
  background-color: #0000FF;
  background-image: url('bg2.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  color: white;
}
```

**Edit:** I fixed it by setting the margin and pading of the body to 0px. I'm making the background like this so I can animate them separately.

Comment: Did you try setting `padding: 0;` for your `#bg`? What is your `div` inside of? Use the inspection window of your browser (in Chrome, right click your image and select "inspect"). It will show you where all the margins and paddings are and what elements they are applying to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please add more of your HTML and possibly placeholder images (use a service like https://via.placeholder.com)? Right now, it's hard to determine what you're actually asking.

Comment: @lurker This worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few considerations:

1. **How tall is the `div`?**: By default, a `div` is only high as its content height. That is, for instance, a `div` with 5 lines text in it is only 5 lines tall. If the background image is taller than the `div` height, it'll also be clipped at that height.

   - **Suggestion:** Perhaps give the `div` a particular height or/and try `background-size`
2. **Is the `div` *only* for background layering?**: In other words, can the `background-image` be moved to the `body` itself, so the the `background` attributes are controlled in the same element?

   - **Suggestion:** Perhaps use multiple `background-image`s as illustrated in [**MDN doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)